# Stop WindowBuilder for Eclipse putting components inside brackets

Tags: swing, eclipse-plugin, brackets, windowbuilder

Is there a way to stop *WindowBuilder* for Eclipse putting components (JButton, JComboBox etc.) inside brackets when adding them to design?

```
{
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    contentPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    {
        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the preferences, `Windowbuilder/Swing/Code Generation`, set the `Statement generation` to `Flat` (which is the default):

[image]